# Magento 2 - Adding custom CSS to admin backend

Tags: css, admin, magento2

I am trying to add some custom CSS to the admin backend but I am not sure where to add this. Can someone please advise on the best practice for doing this.

Answer (score 5):

you need to add a custom module and define css in desired xml or if you want to add in all pages create **default.xml**

1) add a module Ex. Emizentech/NewAdmin

2) create a new file **view/adminhtml/layout/default.xml** in the module

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <head>
     <css src="css/emizentech.css"/>
   </head>
</page>
```

3) Add .css file in web folder as below path:

```
view/adminhtml/web/css/emizentech.css
```

after this you need to clear cache and deploy static content

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: Need Some changes in default.xml file: `<?xml version="1.0"?> <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"> <head> <css src="Vendor_Module::css/test.css"/> </head> </page>`